# Attempt to read property on null (Laravel 8) only on POST

Tags: php, laravel

I have create a function in Controller just for **POST request** that is being used by Stripe Webhook.

```
$customer_referal = StripePayments::where('payment_intent', $charge->payment_intent)->first()->worker_id;
```

POST request gives me an error:

```
ErrorException: Attempt to read property &quot;worker_id&quot; on null in file /var/www/panel/app/Jobs/StripeWebhooks/ChargeSucceededJob.php on line 60
```

This is not a standard issue, because I already tried debugging using `echo` and `dd`, and they are showing right results. For example, using `echo` on `$charge->payment_intent` is giving me a `string` (I also checked the type).

When I run the same command on another function, it gives me a result. Whenever I try the same thing, it always works, expect on this POST function that gives me an error output like this.

How it is possible for this query to work everywhere, except this function that has nothing special on it?

Comment: Apparently it couldn't find that stripe payment. Get the record, make sure it exists, then get the worker_id.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? Getting the same issue with a webhook only on 3D secure payments.

Comment: @HashimAziz Yes, and aynber was right. I believe that you did the same mistake. In my case, I was using Development Environment on Stripe where you get a different API keys for your Webhook, but other Stripe keys were on Production. So, at the end, I was using test-webhook on production Payment Intent. You probably mixed them somewhere and that's the reason why it fails or you are using different URL for the webhook. Check everything step-by-step, good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is pretty clear, it means there is no Stripe payment with the given payment_intent ID.

You can catch the error like this:

```
try {
     $customer_referal = StripePayments::where('payment_intent', $charge->payment_intent)
        ->firstOrFail();
} catch(ModelNotFoundException $e) {
     // payment is not found, do what you want
     dd($e);
}

echo $customer_referal->worker_id;
```

Comment: Is the `try...catch` really necessary when already using `firstOrFail()`?